# Mysql error in time to insert registration information

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code to insert registration information

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name 
                  (idmembers,name,email,phone,
                   jn_dt,pan,pwd,
                   enroller_id,enrolled_id,tside) 
              VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone',
                      '$jn_dt', '$pan', '$pwd', 
                      '$enroller_id', '$enrolled_id', '$tside')";

    $data = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());

    if($data) { 
         header("location:registration.php?sucessful=true");

}
```

but I am getting the error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'hjkoputrd', '123654', 'F' at line 16"... Please help me.. thanks in advance..

Comment: You should also include the mysql error number into your question. (e.g. `ERROR 1064 (42000)`). And... someone has to say it: `mysql*` functions are deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. Use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 2):

You are inserting field idmembers, but you dont use it in values.

If your idmembers column is autoincrementing you do not have to specify it in query.

```
"INSERT INTO $tbl_name (name,email,phone,jn_dt,pan,pwd,enroller_id,enrolled_id,tside) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone', '$jn_dt', '$pan', '$pwd', '$enroller_id', '$enrolled_id', '$tside')"
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't including anything into `idmembers`. If is `autoincrement` in  `idmembers` set to true, `idmembers` will be included and set automatically, so you must remove it from your query.

Answer (score 0):

I think column `idmembers` is your PRIMARY KEY auto increament thats way you are not using it in VALUES.

If it is a PK than just remove that column from your query.

Comment: @posthumus can u share db structure

Comment: And chk what r u getting in $enrolled_id and whats datatype of this column? @posthumus

Comment: @posthumus.. ok my friend.. now debug yur query... use this ....... echo $query = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name 
                  (idmembers,name,email,phone,
                   jn_dt,pan,pwd,
                   enroller_id,enrolled_id,tside) 
              VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone',
                      '$jn_dt', '$pan', '$pwd', 
                      '$enroller_id', '$enrolled_id', '$tside')"; exit;

Comment: And check what r u getting and run this query on phpmyadmin

Comment: there is no problem... :(

Comment: Sory I cant chat with u bcoz u dont have points. Well plz copy yur insert query and update in yur question... and mention u run on phpmyadmin. @posthumus

Comment: I have solved the problem just now the problem is date column in database is of type varchar and generating current date is in date format so it conflicting...  Thanks all of you for spending your valuable time...

Comment: Ahan congrats thats way I suggest u to show schema or structure... one more thing this also happended due to ` backticks in some cases . @posthumus